# Using SparklyR Spark install to run Scala code in R

Tags: r, scala, apache-spark, rstudio, sparklyr

Looking to use the custom `scalac` (Scala Compiler) included with `sparklyr` Spark install; found in the RStudio SparkUI tab (or from `spark_web(sc)`) >> Environment >> `/jars/scala-compiler-2.11.8.jar` as a "System Environment" -- instead of separately downloading and installing `scalac` in the base directories -- as suggested in [the "hello world" example found here](https://github.com/jjallaire/sparkhello) and linked from RStudio's page on Creating Extensions http://spark.rstudio.com/extensions.html.

Here is what I have so far, using Ubuntu, but stalled out at the error below. I set up a directory exactly the same as the Github-repo used in the "hello world" example above. Know how to get past this error without installing in one of the suggested base path folders -- i.e., `/opt/scala`, `/opt/local/scala`, `/usr/local/scala`, or `~/scala` (Windows-only)? Want to use the `sparklyr` native installation and relative path for a given user.

```
library(titanic)
library(sparklyr)

# spark_web(sc) # Opens Web Console to find Scala Version and scalac

# Sets Working Directory to R folder of file
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))

sparkVers <- '2.0.0'; scalaVers <- '2.11.8'; packageName <- "sparkhello"
packageJarExtR <- spark_compilation_spec(spark_version = sparkVers, 
                   spark_home = spark_home_dir(), 
                   scalac_path = paste0(spark_home_dir(),"/jars","/scala-compiler-", scalaVers, ".jar"), #
                   scala_filter = NULL, 
                   jar_name = sprintf(paste0(getwd(),"/inst/java/", packageName, "-%s-%s.jar"), sparkVers, scalaVers) 
                   )

sparklyr::compile_package_jars(spec = packageJarExtR)

# Error: No root directory found. Test criterion:
#   Contains a file 'DESCRIPTION' with contents matching '^Package: '
# In addition: Warning message:
#   running command ''/mnt/home/eyeOfTheStorm/.cache/spark/
#   spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/scala-compiler-2.11.8.jar' 
#     -version 2>&1' had status 126



### 

library(sparkhello) 

# Connect to local spark cluster and load data
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", version = "2.0.0")
titanic_tbl <- copy_to(sc, titanic_train, "titanic", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

the error occurred because of the wrong working directory, it mustn't be the R directory.

first, you must create an R package (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9PyQlbAEujY) "to be sparklyr extension package" and name it sparkhello.
then, create in it three folders :

1) the R folder: contain hello.R which is the R warper for your scala code and the dependencies.R file(as shown in the example of hello world)

2) the JAVA folder : contain your scala code in a .scala file

3) inst/java folder : later it will contain your jars that they will be created automatically after executing :

```
sparklyr::compile_package_jars()
```

(important file-) the description file : you can create it your self or copy and past the file available with sparhello example

after that, built your package and then check your working directory with

```
getwd()
```

you must find it pointing to the package you have created it("/home/"user"/sparkhello") if not change it with

```
setwd("/home/user/sparkhello")
```

after seting the right working directory re-execute the code you mentioned it above